# regex maching after new line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

i am trying to match with regex in perl different parts of a text which are not in the same line.

I have a file sized 200 mb aprox with all cases similar to the following example:

> rewfww
>
> vfresrgt
>
> rter
>
> *** BLOCK 049 Aeee/Ed "ewewew"U 141202 0206
>
> BLAH1
>
> BLAH2
>
> END

and i want to extract all what is in the same line after the "***" in $1, BLAH1 in $2 and BLAH2 in $3.

i have tried the following without success:

open(archive, "C:/Users/g/Desktop/blahs.txt") or die "die\n";

```
while(< archive>){
    if($_ =~ /^\*\*\*(.*)\n(.*)/s){
        print $1;
        print $2;
    }
 }
```

One more complexity: i don´t know how many BLAH´s are in each case. Perhaps one case have only BLAH1, other case  with BLAH1, BLAH2 and BLAH3 etc. The only thing thats sure is the final "END" who separates the cases.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

```
\*\*\*([^\n]*)\n|(?!^)\G\s*(?!\bEND\b)([^\n]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/17

Comment: perfect, thats what i want but where i put this thing in the code that i have posted?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $archive, '<', "C:/Users/g/Desktop/blahs.txt") or die "die: $!";
while(<$archive>){
    if (/^\*{3}/ .. /END/) {
        s/^\*{3}//;
        print unless /END/;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question the following works for me. Please update or provide feedback if you are looking for something more or less strict (or spot any mistakes!).

`^(\*{3}.*\n{2})(([a-zA-Z])*([0-9]*)\n{2})*(END)$`

`^(\*{3}\n{2})`   - Find line consisting of three *s followed by two newlines - You could repeat this by adding * after the last closing parenthesis if you want/need to check for a "false" start. While it looks like you may have data in the file before this but this is the start of the data you actually care about/want to capture.

`(([a-zA-Z])*([0-9]*)\n{2})*`  -The desired word characters followed by a number (or numbers if your BLAH count >9) and also check for two trailing spaces. The * at the end denotes that this can repeat zero or more times which accounts for the case where you have  no data. If you want a fail if there is not data use ? instead of * to denote it must repeat 1 or more times. **this segment assumes you wanted to check for data in the format word+number. If that is not the case this part can be easily modified to accept a wider range of data - let me know if you want/need a more or less strict case**

`(END)$`        - The regex ends with sequence "END". If it is permissible for the data to continue and you just want to stop capture at this point do not include the $

I don't have permissions to post pics yet but a great site to check and to see a visual representation of your regex imo is https://www.debuggex.com/